# Batch program to Delete everything in txt after fifth slash

Tags: windows, cmd

I have multiple txt files with multiple links in it which have to be trimmed after five slashes.
The batch file should delete everything in the line in the .txt file after the fifth slash, how could I do this?

Example of a .txt file:
Before:
`http://www.website.net/sr/PD2QPVGPRH2/?NameOfTheFile_05_720p.rar
http://www.website.net/sr/SWLYPVGPRNV/?NameOfTheFile_05_1080p.part1.rar
http://www.website.net/sr/23IXPVGPWXFO/?NameOfTheFile_05_1080p.part2.rar`

Afterwards:
`http://www.website.net/sr/PD2QPVGPRH2/
http://www.website.net/sr/SWLYPVGPRNV/
http://www.website.net/sr/23IXPVGPWXFO/`

Thanks in advance! ^^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code on 
where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You can [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: If your sample with the `?` question mark applies to **all** your files I'd use a `for /f` and split with `for /f "delims=?"`

Comment: @LotPings - The `for` loop does not seem to like `?` characters. No amount of escaping them has worked yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a file `sample.txt` in current diretory:

```
http://www.website.net/sr/PD2QPVGPRH2/?NameOfTheFile_05_720p.rar
http://www.website.net/sr/SWLYPVGPRNV/?NameOfTheFile_05_1080p.part1.rar
http://www.website.net/sr/23IXPVGPWXFO/?NameOfTheFile_05_1080p.part2.rar
```

This batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\31\SO_53088499.cmd
@Echo off
For %%F in (*.txt) Do (
  For /f "delims=?" %%A in (%%F) Do Echo:%%A
)
```

will output:

```
> SO_53088499.cmd
http://www.website.net/sr/PD2QPVGPRH2/
http://www.website.net/sr/SWLYPVGPRNV/
http://www.website.net/sr/23IXPVGPWXFO/
```

This could easily be redirected to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to end the string on exactly the fifth (5th) SOLIDUS (slash), then a `FOR` loop like this could be used. Note that this is very specific to URL strings. The `FOR` loop delimiters do not provide an element in the case of successive delimiters.

Data file containing the URL strings.

```
C:>type urltrim.txt
http://www.website.net/sr/PD2QPVGPRH2/?NameOfTheFile_05_720p.rar
http://www.website.net/sr/SWLYPVGPRNV/?NameOfTheFile_05_1080p.part1.rar
http://www.website.net/sr/23IXPVGPWXFO/?NameOfTheFile_05_1080p.part2.rar
```

Code to read the strings and truncate.

```
C:>type urltrim.bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=/ tokens=1-4" %%a IN (urltrim.txt) DO (
    echo %%a//%%b/%%c/%%d/
)
```

A sample execution.

```
C:>CALL urltrim.bat
http://www.website.net/sr/PD2QPVGPRH2/
http://www.website.net/sr/SWLYPVGPRNV/
http://www.website.net/sr/23IXPVGPWXFO/
```